# Ubuntu unlock screen is "checking password..." too slow

Tags: login, performance, unity-2d, login-screen, authentication

**Question**

When I don't use my laptop (with Ubuntu 11.10 (x64) and Unity 2d) for 5-10 minutes, it automatically locks. After that, when I'm trying to unlock it, it asks for the password. After I enter a password, it takes a random time from about 1 to about 100 seconds for it to unlock.

Are there any ways to speed up the unlock screen?

**What was done**

- Found [a similar question](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=905575) on ubuntuforums.org suggests to look at [bug #515155](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver/+bug/515155), which suggests that the problem has something to do with pam_ecryptfs. Using instructions, described there, I've looked at my `etc/pam.d/common-auth` file, but it says nothing about `pam_encryptfs`.
- Searched `/var/log/syslog.log` for information. Nothing useful.
- Searched `/var/log/auth.log` for information. I've found the following messages there, dated to unlock time:

  ```
  gnome-screensaver-dialog: pam_krb5(gnome-screensaver:auth): authentication failure; logname=victor uid=1000 euid=1000 tty=:0.0 ruser= rhost=
  gnome-screensaver-dialog: gkr-pam: unlocked login keyring
  ```

  I haven't used `su` and `sudo` for a few hours. At the time of these messages I've just logged in.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).